# Image picked from gallery and took from camera looks horizontally stretched android

Tags: android

I am working on a piece of code that captures image through camera as well as picks image from gallery and setting it to the imageview in the listview .

The problem is ..

1. both the image returned by camera as well as gallery looks horizontally stretches
2. the camera intent not works(not returns data ie: camera stucks in saving image) with every camera apps that is available in the device

Example:
works with ----- stock camera ,HD camera

doesn't work with ------ Camera MX, Camera FX

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
                View view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);
                ImageView imgView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);                
                Bitmap bitmap=(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                byte bitObj[]=BirthdayCalculation.convertImageToByte(bitmap);
                Log.v("Photo byte.......", bitObj.toString());              
                ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                values.put(BirthdayProvider.PHOTO, bitObj);
                int count=getContentResolver().update(BirthdayProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, BirthdayProvider.NUMBER+"='"+SearchListActivity.longClickValue+"'", null);
                if (count==1) {
                    finish();
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 85, 80, false));                   
                    Log.v("Photo Updated Successfully", "Photo Updated Successfully");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updation Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }              
            }
        }

        else if (requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {            
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                try {
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()), null, o);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
                int scale = 1;

                while(true) {
                    if(width_tmp / 2 < 200 || height_tmp / 2 < 200)
                        break;
                    width_tmp /= 2;
                    height_tmp /= 2;
                    scale *= 2;
                }

                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()), null, o2);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                byte bitObj[]=BirthdayCalculation.convertImageToByte(bitmap);
                Log.v("bitObj[]", bitObj.toString());
                ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                values.put(BirthdayProvider.PHOTO, bitObj);
                int count=getContentResolver().update(BirthdayProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, BirthdayProvider.NUMBER+"='"+SearchListActivity.longClickValue+"'", null);
                if (count==1) {
                    finish();
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    Log.v("Photo Updated Successfully", "Photo Updated Successfully");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updation Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }              
              }
            }
        }
```

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <!-- THUMBAIL IMAGE -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="85dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:shadowColor="#585858"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="20"
            android:src="@drawable/karthik" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Facebook Friend"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!-- ARROW IMAGE -->


    <!-- NAME -->
    <!-- CONTACT NUMBER -->


    <!-- BIRTHDATE -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_row"
        android:text="KARTHIK.KOLANJI"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_zodiac"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="Sagittarius"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_turns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:text="24"
        android:textColor="#990000"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="Next birthday on : "
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="Wednesday"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_name"
        android:text="9594080469"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15dip" 
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sub_title_category"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
        android:text="turns"
        android:textColor="#996600"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_days_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="36"
        android:textColor="#990000"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_width="15dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_row"
        android:contentDescription="Zodiac icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:shadowColor="#8B4513"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="20" 
        android:src="@drawable/rings_icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:text="(Anniversary)"
        android:textColor="#787878"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
        android:text="Zodiac :  "
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="7th, April 1990"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtview_turns"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:text=" days left"
        android:textColor="#996600"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="Zodiac icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:shadowColor="#8B4513"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="20" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: karthik , not sure , but i think , your image Size , and image view size is a problem !

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" this in your layout will help you to scale your image

Comment: I also posted imageview layout

Comment: @mohammed momn ---- android:scaleType="fitXY" already used in imageview

Comment: could you post your layout ??

Comment: I think , your image-width is not good for handling , 85dp_imageView !

Comment: @ Tushar Pandey ---- what is the way to achieve it ????

Comment: handle your view with , according to your Image-width , that's the best way . for this you will need dp-px / px-dp convertor . 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2qhxuc7g6lg58wa/dptopx_pxtoDp.txt

Comment: you cannot handle or get perfect image , if your image width is 10px and you want 30px image , definitely your image will distort , by my code , you can only handle , dp-px conversion .

Comment: @ Tushar Pandey --- can u suggest any other way to do this ??